# Java convert SVG string into PNG file

Tags: java, excel, apache

I have svg string which is svg from chart:

```
String svg = chart.getSVG();
```

String looks like `<svg>...<g>...</g>...</svg>` and so on.
Now i want to save it into Excel with method

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
wb.addPicture(safeDataBytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
```

The problem is I don't know how to create PNG from this SVG String...
I don't need to save this file.
Already i tryied:

```
byte[] safeDataBytes = new byte[0];
                            try {
                                safeDataBytes = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(svg);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: As the name says, SVG is vector based. You'll need to render it at a specific resolution and colour depth to a bitmap, and then serialize that bitmap as png.